Mermaid/siren sitting on a rock talking gibberish
I've been trying to find this movie for years but have been unsuccessful since I only remember a few seconds of it.
I remember a man peeling an orange while talking to another man and there was a mermaid/siren sitting on a rock in the background. 
The background looked tropical and I think the guy peeling the orange was wearing sunglasses and a typical Hawaiian shirt. I don't remember what the other man looked like. The mermaid/siren was blonde and she didn't speak, but she made weird gibberish sounds. 

Splash:

A man is reunited with a mermaid who saves him from drowning as a boy and falls in love not knowing who/what she is. 

The guy in the Hawaiian shirt is John Candy, who is the lead (Tom Hanks)'s brother. They own an orange shipping facility on the water. There's a scene where Candy is peeling an orange and talking to Hanks.
The mermaid is played by Daryll Hannah. Long wavy blonde hair, and at some points she does speak gibberish...especially when asked her name.
